# .htaccess RewriteRule for SEO URL allow "-" symbol

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite

My code is:

```
Options -Multiviews

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9]+)\.html$ /index.php?cat=$1 [L]
```

I am new to htaccess and I can't find how to allow "-" symbol to url

For example, if i am accessing `mysite.com/categoryname.html` it works but if I am accessing `mysite.com/category-name.html` it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply add to your character sets the "-" symbol.

`([a-z0-9]+)` will be `([a-z0-9-]+)`

Comment: Since it works, please consider accepting the answer. :)